# Where is the documentation for OGNL officially kept now?

Tags: struts2, ognl, opensymphony

The OpenSymphony page no longer has it.  A link to ognl.org from the Struts 2 documentation is also dead.  So where is the official OGNL site now?

**UPDATE EDIT**

As of August 2011, it graduated from Incubator to Apache Commons.  [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/download_ognl.cgi) has its own site now, though an ominous "Coming soon (or not)" message is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be in limbo at the moment. OGNL was accepted into the Apache Incubator a little while back, so once incubation is finished, I'd expect to see it at the new OGNL project site.

For now, you may want to follow the incubation status at: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/ognl.html

I know that the OpenSymphony site just shut down very recently and caught quite a few people off guard.

**Edit**

I posed the question to the Struts developer list and received responses that echoed my answer. You can probably find the documentation in SVN if its urgent, otherwise it should be included on the OGNL project website when incubation is completed. You could also try using the Wayback Machine to find it on archived copies of the OpenSymphony site.

**Update**

The Apache OGNL incubator site is now up: http://incubator.apache.org/ognl/

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenSymphony](http://www.opensymphony.com/) pages are entitled 'OpenSymphony, RIP (2000 - 2011)' and explain what has happened to that.  Sub-pages such as `http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl` lead to the top page too (which is reasonable and sensible).

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGNL) page needs to be updated to recognize the changes in the world.
The original [OGNL](http://ognl.org/) web site appears to be missing altogether.

The OpenSymphony WebWork project seems to have migrated to Apache and Struts.  It seems that [OGNL](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/ognl.html) is now an incubator project at Apache (along with OpenOffice, perhaps).  So, you need to go the Apache OGNL web site for the time being, but expect the URL to change if OGNL makes it out of the incubator phase.  (Google is your friend - at least when finding information like this.)

Comment: OpenOffice has not been accepted to Incubator at the time of this writing. It MIGHT go to Apache - but its not sure.